# In what order mysql triggers are invoked during INSERT ON DUPLICATE statement?

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, sql-insert, insert-update

Here is 4 triggers which can be added to mysql table:

1. before insert
2. before update
3. after insert
4. after update

Suppose that all triggers were added to the table. Then the [insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) executed. What trigger are executed and in what order?

Also insert on duplicate supports `column` for access column value and `VALUES(column)` for accessing new inserted value. How do they are mapped to `NEW` and `OLD` variables which are used in triggers?

Answer (score 0):

On insert on duplicate update first it will try to inset data and if it fails then update record. always it will execute only one statement inset or update  so you can expect either insert triggers or update triggers to be triggered. not all

Comment: before and after triggers  will be triggered on before and after